# How to trap the event of JTextField in java?

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a JtextField and a JList, there are 100 items in jlist, i want to trap the event of jtextfield corresponing to jlist, when i type something in textfield as 'B', items related to 'B' in the jlist, i want to see currently in jlist,

Answer (score 2):

To track what is being edited in a JTextField "real-time", you must add a DocumentListener to the document of the JTextField:

```
myTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    // ... implement DocumentListener methods and filter the JList model 
    // each time an event is triggered
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use an ActionListner on the jtextfield
Everytime you write something in the textfield you can do something like see the value of the textfield

let me know

Bye